# Inquiry Regarding NTC Selection and Placement for ST L6924D LiPo Battery Charger

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, thermistor, st

I am planning to create a lithium-polymer (LiPo) battery charger using the ST [L6924D](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6924d.pdf) charging IC. 
 Could you kindly recommend an appropriate NTC (Negative Temperature Coefficient) for controlling battery charging within the temperature range of 0 to 50 degrees?
Additionally, is it necessary to affix the NTC directly onto the battery?
[image]

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here. Is there an application note or any examples in the datasheet you can use? If not, you can calculate it from TH set point, Vref and your R7/R10 voltage divider.

Comment: If you're trying to sense the battery temperature, then yes, the thermistor needs to be thermally bonded as tightly as possible to the battery. If you're trying to sense the ambient temperature, then no, you want the thermistor as far from the battery as you can manage.